# how to retain the state of activity in android

Tags: android

How do I retain the state of an activity in android? I have two layouts for portrait and landscape in layout and layout-land. I am loading the value from service at the time I am showing progress dialog. If loaded user rotates the device to landscape at the time also loading. How do I avoid that? user typed content in webview that also refreshed. How do I avoid that, can anybody provide an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onRetainNonConfigurationChange()` callback to store arbitrary data. It is called just before your application is about to be recreated.

Then, in `onCreate()` just check if some data were put aside by calling `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` that returns the Object you put aside or null.

See [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) on android developers.

Here's a sample borrowed from the link above:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    //this is called by the framework when needed
    //Just return what you want to save here.

    return MyBigObjectThatContainsEverythingIWantToSave;
}
```

Automagic restore of previously saved state:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final MyDataObject MyBigObjectThatContainsEverythingIWantToSave = (MyDataObject) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (MyBigObjectThatContainsEverythingIWantToSave == null) {
        //No saved state
        MyBigObjectThatContainsEverythingIWantToSave = loadMyData();
    } else {
        //State was restored, no need to download again.
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When orientation changes, the Activity is reloaded by default. If you do not want this behavior then add this to the Activity definition in your manifest:

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

For more detail, see [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: @Laurent I have to save lot of object like textview webview how to save it can u give example thanks

Answer (score 0):

When orientation changes, the Activity is reloaded by default. If you do not want this behavior then add this to the Activity definition in your android manifest file :

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"