# Button Background not changing as desired

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

Does anyone know why this code is not changing the background image of my button as desired?

```
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Size: " + Order.getInstance().getOrderItems().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    price.setText(String.valueOf(Order.getInstance().getAmount()));


    if(Order.getInstance().getOrderItems().size() > 0 && sent == false){

        sendBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.confirmOrder);
        sendBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sendBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.send);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Review Order Screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ReviewOrderActivity.class);
                sent = true;
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }else if(sent == true){
        sendBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.confirmOrder);
        sendBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sendBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pay);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Pay Order Screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), PayActivity.class);
                //startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

If the user presses the button the first time it should set a `Boolean` to true and start the new Activity. From within the new activity when the user presses a button to return to the previous activity it should now set the image to be different because the `Boolean` is set to true.

For some reason it is not working...any help is much appreciated!

This is the code within Activity 2 which returns user to previous activity when button pressed:

```
sendBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.confirmOrder);
    sendBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    sendBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.confirm);
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent k = new Intent(v.getContext(), SectionsActivity.class);
            int tableNum = Order.getInstance().getTableNumber();
            int coverNum = Order.getInstance().getCoverNumber();

            itemNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Get dishes from order
            for(int i = 0; i < orderItems.size(); i++){
                MenuItem item = orderItems.get(i);
                String itemName = item.getName();
                itemNames.add(i, itemName);
            }

            RequestTask requestTask = new RequestTask(url, String.valueOf(tableNum), String.valueOf(coverNum), itemNames);
            ReviewOrderActivity.this.finish();
            //startActivity(k);
        }
    });
```

EDIT TO CODE:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "value: " + sent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    price.setText(String.valueOf(Order.getInstance().getAmount()));


    if(Order.getInstance().getOrderItems().size() > 0 && sent == false){

        sendBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.confirmOrder);
        sendBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sendBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.send);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Review Order Screen " + sent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ReviewOrderActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            }
        });
    }else if(sent == true){
        sendBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.confirmOrder);
        sendBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sendBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pay);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Pay Order Screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), PayActivity.class);
                //startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

      if (requestCode == 1) {

         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
             sent = true;       
         }
         if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
             sent = false;
         }
      }
    }//onActivityResult
```

In second Activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_review);

    //Get order items from application and assign to list
    orderItems = Order.getInstance().getOrderItems();

    sendBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.confirmOrder);
    sendBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    sendBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.confirm);
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent k = new Intent(v.getContext(), SectionsActivity.class);
            int tableNum = Order.getInstance().getTableNumber();
            int coverNum = Order.getInstance().getCoverNumber();

            itemNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Get dishes from order
            for(int i = 0; i < orderItems.size(); i++){
                MenuItem item = orderItems.get(i);
                String itemName = item.getName();
                itemNames.add(i, itemName);
            }

            RequestTask requestTask = new RequestTask(url, String.valueOf(tableNum), String.valueOf(coverNum), itemNames);
            setResult(RESULT_OK); //EDIT

            ReviewOrderActivity.this.finish();
            //startActivity(k);
        }
    });


    //Create adapter and set to the list
    adapter = new ReviewOrderArrayAdapter(this, orderItems);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `sent == true` when you go through `onResume()`?

Comment: @codeMagic after checking that I noticed that `sent == false` when the user is returned to it...can't think of why the variable is being reset though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no guarantee that Android won't clear out your `variables` or even your `Activity` if it needs the memory or that the GC won't nab it up, you need to handle the storage of these `variables` in `onPause()`. You can store them in `SharedPrefs` so that you can retrieve them in `onResume()`

Another, possibly simpler, option for what you need would be to use `StartActivityForResult()` and in `setResult()` of your `SecondActivity` would be to pass back a `RESULT_CODE` indicating to change the `variable` to `true`. Then you wouldn't need to set it in your `FirstActivity`

From the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult)

> requestCode   If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.

you should look for the `REQUEST_CODE` that you sent. This way you can use `startActivityForResult` multiple times in the same `Activity` if you need for different things

Comment: That's true and not true at the same time. First, DO NOT use SharedPreferences for state! Use onRetain.. in the Activity (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782876/how-to-retain-the-state-of-activity-in-android) ). Second, I doubt that's what's happening here - it's far more likely that the variable is getting reset somewhere else (onStart is a good possible culprit). One way to know for sure would be to actually use a Boolean object. If it's being cleaned, it will be null, not false.

Comment: I understand your point and there likely could be something else. But I think this is a good place to start because it should take care of the OP's current problem and help eliminate future problems. It isn't saving "state" but a variable to tell it what to do when it returns. It actually wants to change the state instead of keep it. `SharedPrefs` may not be the best solution which is why I suggested `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: I think to keep it simple I am going to try your second option. Will let you know how I get on! Thank you for the help

Comment: I think that's the better option in this case but thought I'd leave the other there for others if needed. Good luck and hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this and it did not help...I included the edits to my code above if you wouldn't mind looking.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but I don't see where you changed the code. You were going to use `startActivityForResult()`, right?

Comment: Yep, It should be there in the code below the EDIT `startActivityForResult(i, 0);`

Comment: Sorry, it must be late, I don't know how I missed that. Anyway, you are sending `REQUEST_CODE` 0 but looking for `REQUEST_CODE == 0` in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: No problem mate, so should I be looking for `REQUEST_CODE == 1`? When I check the `REQUEST_CODE` in `onActivityResult()` it is 0 at the moment

Comment: I managed to get it sorted. The issue was that I was setting the result after the activity was finishing. I just moved `setResult()` to before `ReviewOrderActivity.this.finish()` and the problem cleared up. Also in my `onPostExecute()` I was starting the same activity so it was being created twice. I removed this code. Thank you for your help

Comment: Guess I should have realized you were doing that. Glad you got it going. You're welcome